# Query with double joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

**My entities are:**  Characters -  Stats - Cards

**The relationship between then is simple:**

Characters have one-to-one for Stats

Characters have one-to-many for Cards

**The expected query result is :**

*card.id, character.name, characters.thumbnail, characters.type, stats.overall*

P.S: Cards and Stats have not direct relation, but Characters have a stat_id column

**Resuming**

How it's possible to in a single query achieve the expected result?

**My attempts:**

```
SELECT 
    cards.id, characters.thumbnail, characters.type, characters.name
FROM 
    cards
INNER JOIN 
    characters 
ON cards.character_id=characters.id
```

*Result*

*cards.id, characters.thumbnail, characters.type, characters.name*

**Attempt to get stats.overall:**

```
SELECT 
    cards.id, characters.thumbnail, characters.type, characters.name, stats.overall
FROM 
    cards, characters
INNER JOIN 
    characters 
ON cards.character_id=characters.id
INNER JOIN 
    stats 
ON characters.stat_id=stats.id
```

*Result*

*error: table name "characters" specified more than once*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are joining twice to `characters` table , please avoid using implicit joins ( using , to join tables ) , always use explicit join :

```
SELECT
    cards.id
    , characters.thumbnail
    , characters.type
    , characters.name
    , stats.overall
FROM
    cards
    INNER JOIN characters
        ON cards.character_id = characters.id
    INNER JOIN stats
        ON characters.stat_id = stats.id
```